# Rabies transmission via barking

Tags: virology, infectious-diseases

[According to CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/rabies/exposure/type.html), non-bite exposure includes scratches, abrasion, and contamination of the mucous membrane from a rabid animal's saliva.

So, is it possible to catch rabies if a rapid animal barks near you? I mean, it can have some tiny droplets of saliva on it, right? Or the contamination of the mucous membrane should come from licks as stated by [WHO](http://www.who.int/rabies/about/home_treatment/en/)?

Answer (score 4):

> Between 1956 and 1977, 4 human cases of rabies virus infection were
>   attributed to aerosolized rabies virus;

Possible but very rare.

https://academic.oup.com/jid/article/195/8/1144/816583